# Python calling class from other file does not wait until all values are entered

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I am trying to write a python script that will allow me to connect to multiple ssh servers at the same time and execute commands below is the code that I am using when I try and run the main.py script, it keeps telling me that the run_multiple_clients function is missing its params screenshot below, does anyone know how I can make this function wait until the required vars are entered and then execute the function

```html
/*sshClients.py*/
import asyncio, asyncssh
import mmap
import sys

class Clients:
    async def run_client(host, command, username, password):
        async with asyncssh.connect(host, username, password) as conn:
            return await conn.run(command)

    async def run_multiple_clients(command, username, password):
        
        choose = input('choose your host set (1-5) ')
        hosts = Hosts.sampleHosts(choose)

        tasks = (run_client(host, command, username, password) for host in hosts)
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

        for i, result in enumerate(results, 1):
            if isinstance(result, Exception):
                print('Task %d failed: %s' % (i, str(result)))
            elif result.exit_status != 0:
                print('Task %d exited with status %s:' % (i, result.exit_status))
                print(result.stderr, end='')
            else:
                print('Task %d succeeded:' % i)
                print(result, end='')
                

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run_multiple_clients())

class Hosts:
    def sampleHosts(host):
        switcher={
                0:['192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10'],
                1:['192.168.1.1', '192.168.22.55'],
             }
        return switcher.get(host,"Invalid host number")

/*main.py*/

from sshClients import Clients

def start():
    username = input('username')
    password = input('password')
    command = input('command you would like to execute')
    Clients.run_multiple_clients(username, password, command)

#Calling the start funciton to kick things off
start()
```

If anyone can suggest a better way to do this it would be appreciated

This is the error I am getting

[image]

Comment: You call the function as `run_multiple_clients()`, even though it takes arguments as the error says. You need to pass the required data into the function.

Comment: Do you even need that call though? You call the same function correctly later on, although it seems like that call needs to be tied into the event loop.

Comment: My thinking is if I call it in the main.py script I can pass the arguments through or am I better off just getting rid of main.py and just having the vars in the same function